# OpenJDK cross-compilation couldn't find X11 libraries but packages are installed

Tags: java, openjdk-11

Cross-compiling openJDK 11 fork following this instruction https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/blob/master/doc/building.md#cross-compiling-the-easy-way-with-openjdk-devkits

```
 make TARGETS="aarch64-linux-gnu" BASE_OS=Fedora BASE_OS_VERSION=21 &>build.log
```

is done well, but

```
./configure --with-devkit=./build/devkit/x86_64-linux-gnu/aarch64-linux-gnu --openjdk-target=aarch64-linux-gnu && make
```

Produces the following output: https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/a523cae108db6ff961d5a95c1d86c6fb
But I have already installed `libx11-dev libxext-dev libxrender-dev libxrandr-dev libxtst-dev libxt-dev`

Comment: Have you installed `openjdk-11-jdk` or `openjdk-11-jdk-headless`?

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed those libraries *for the correct architecture*? If you cross-compile then just running the command verbatim will install the default architecture of the machine you're running on, but you need the headers for the target architecture. I.e. something like `apt install libx11-dev:arm64`.

Comment: @dan1st Nope. I have jdk 10 in PATH installed manually.

Comment: @JoachimSauer "Unable to locate package libx11-dev:arm64" I am sorry I'm not clearly understand what do you mean, please provide a link for details.